# Why the selectbox val() ,it has to values

Tags: javascript, jquery

I have a select box which has an attribute `class='check_quantity'`

```
$('.check_quantity').each(function(){
        quantities.push($(this).val());
    });
```

When I use console.log(quantities);

```
["1", ""]
```

it outputs like this,why there is a empty value in the array?

Comment: because one of the elements with class `check_quantity` have empty value or no value.

Comment: One of the element in empty, it could be anything inside your select box.That's why it is appending empty value. Best way to debug is printout all the element for debug purpose and check.

Answer (score 0):

use **[map()](http://api.jquery.com/jquery.map/)** in jquery to get the value into array()

```
var quantities=$('.check_quantity').map(function(){
        if ($.trim(this.value) != "") {  // this.value.trim() != "" it is pure java script better to use this 
            return this.value;
        }
    }).get();
```

NOTE:`.check_quantity` has some null value(no value) ,so in this case You have to check null value and  return

**[DEMO](http://jsfiddle.net/6fopbhcf/)**

Comment: How does this answer the question?

Comment: and instead of `.trim()` try using `$.trim()`

Comment: Uncaught TypeError: Cannot read property 'trim' of undefined .there is such an error why?

Comment: @FelixKling You have see  NOTE in my post , and also i gave solution for him ,

Comment: @makenai...yes try my above comment.

Comment: @makenai: Because not every browser supports `String#trim` yet. *edit:* Actually, most of them do: https://kangax.github.io/compat-table/es5/#String.prototype.trim . Maybe you are using IE8 ?

Comment: @makenai see link http://jsfiddle.net/6fopbhcf/1/   syntex ($.trim(this.value) != "")   http://api.jquery.com/jquery.trim/